# Some groups show no members in Get-ADGroup

Tags: powershell

So I have a question about strange PowerShell behavior with `Get-ADGroup`. If I use it on a group I created, I can get members just fine. But on some (not all) built in groups, including **Domain Users**, it returns nothing. See:

```
PS C:\> Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * | Where {$_.name -eq "Iron Throne"} | Select -ExpandProperty members
CN=robert,OU=Baratheons,DC=seven-kingdoms,DC=local
CN=daenerys,OU=Targaryens,DC=seven-kingdoms,DC=local
CN=margaery,OU=Tyrells,DC=seven-kingdoms,DC=local
CN=joffrey,OU=Baratheons,DC=seven-kingdoms,DC=local
CN=Cersei Lannister,OU=Lannisters,DC=seven-kingdoms,DC=local

PS C:\> Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * | Where {$_.name -eq "Domain Users"} | Select -ExpandProperty members

PS C:\>
```

They show up fine in *Active Directory Users and Computers*. This is on a Win2012R2 DC as Administrator. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user's primary group will not be listed when querying `member` or `memberOf` with many utilities. As "Domain Users" is the default primary group for domain users, often this group will appear empty to queries. You may consider querying the [`primaryGroupId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679375(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute as well.

See:
[Setting Primary Group Excludes the User from the Group Membership in Active Directory](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/275523)